# Why does `Self` require a constant size at compile time for calling a free function but the equivalent trait function does not?

Tags: rust, traits

These two functions, one trait and one free, seem to be similar but calling one of them (the trait function) is allowed while calling the other isn't:

```
trait A {
    fn foo(&self) {
        bar(self);    // 1. Error: `Self` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
        A::bar(self); // 2. This works
    }

    fn bar(&self) {}
}

fn bar(_a: &A) {}
```

([Playground link for above](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=63a2b600173571118e34edec120ebd7f&version=stable))

I would have thought in both cases I'm accessing via a pointer whose size *is* known at compile time, so what is the difference and the explanation for this behaviour ?

(Rust 1.19 stable)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the two want totally different things.

The type of `self` inside of `A::foo` is `&Self`, **not** `&A`.  That is, it's a pointer to the implementing type, not a pointer to a trait object.  Calling `A::bar` is fine because it's just passing said pointer along, no extra work necessary.

Calling `::bar` is a whole different cooking vessel of marine life.

The problem boils down to how the compiler represents things.  Let's first consider the case where `Self` is a `Sized` type like `i32`.  This means `self` is a `&i32`.  Recall that `&A` is a trait object, and thus *effectively* has the following layout:

```
struct ATraitObject {
    ptr: *const (),
    vtable: *const AVtable,
}
```

`ATraitObject.ptr` needs to point to the actual value itself, and `ATraitObject.vtable` to the implementation of the trait for that type.  The compiler can fill this out with `ptr` being the existing `self` pointer, and `vtable` is filled with a pointer to wherever the `impl A for i32` vtable lives in memory.  With that, it can call `::bar`.

Now consider the case where `Self` is *not* `Sized`, like `str`.  This means `self` is a "fat" pointer, and contains two pointer's worth of information: a pointer to the underlying data *and* the length of the string.  When the compiler goes to create the `ATraitObject`, it can set `ptr` to `self.as_ptr()`, and it can set `vtable`... but there's nowhere for it to store the string's length!

All non-`Sized` types have this problem, as they all have extra information carried around in their pointers.  Incidentally, this *includes* trait objects like `&A`, meaning that you also can't turn a trait object into *another* trait object, since you'd now need two vtables.

That's the problem: the compiler simply has *no way* of turning `&Self` where `Self: !Sized` into an `&A`.  There's too much information contained in `self` and not enough space to store it in an `&A`.

---

To get the method to compile, add a `where Self: Sized` clause to the method definition.  This guarantees to the compiler that the method will never be called on non-`Sized` types, and thus it's free to assume the conversion from `&Self` to `&A` is always possible.

Comment: Wasn't finished with my big answer, and it contains much the same content, so I will just add that one solution to the problem is to give `foo` a `Sized` constraint: `fn foo(&self) where Self: Sized`. This means you can no longer call `foo` on a trait object reference, though.

Comment: I cut that from mine since the question wasn't "how", but "why".  But might as well.

Comment: Ah didn't know that detail about thin and fat ptrs - i was thinking of C++ kind of layout. Makes sense now - Thanks ! Btw are these layouts (although they are compiler specific and not std in C++ as well but still would help visualise these kind of stuffs) and under the hood stuff detailed/documented somewhere ? Would love to read them.

Comment: @ustulation: Best bet would be to check [The Rustonomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/).

Comment: @DK. Why is `self` inside the trait function `::foo` not a trait object ? How will dynamic dispatch be possible without it ? So say `::foo` called `self.bar()` inside it. Without `self` being a trait object (like `&A`) how would the runtime know which `::bar` to call, the one with the default impl or the one that is overridden by the type implementing the trait ?

Comment: @ustulation: Assuming you mean `A::foo`, not `::foo`: because Rust *doesn't use* dynamic dispatch in that case.  Rust doesn't have inheritance, and the code actually implementing `A` knows what type `self` is, so there's no *need* for dynamic dispatch.

Comment: @DK. yes i meant `A::`, sorry. Ah so you mean the functions with default implementations defined in the trait have no physical existence and every impl of that trait by a concrete type will get separate copies of those (at different mem addresses) ?

Comment: @ustulation: Yes.  Default implementations are copy+pasted into each concrete implementation.